# Ubuntu Linux 14.04 on Parallels Desktop 10, Mac OS X 10.10.2: Parallels and/or Ubuntu update broke Terminal (no command-line prompt)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, mac, parallels

I am running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 via Parallels (10.1.4) in Mac OS X 10.10.2 on a MacBook Pro. Today I received update notifications for Ubuntu (first) and then Parallels and stupidly installed them (I never learn; I have problems every time).

Now when I open `gnome-terminal` (not the Mac Terminal, the Ubuntu one), I have no command-line prompt.  So I can't use `gnome-terminal`.  I have tried reinstalling Parallels tools, but nothing changes.

I don't know whether the Parallels or Ubuntu update created the problem, but I suspect it was the Ubuntu update.  After a few minutes, the following error appears in a terminal:

```
Unknown processor type for Linux 
bash : [: -eq: unary operator expected 
Your "" operating system is not supported by this release of
XXX.
```

XXX is a program I use via Parallels.

Is there a way to undo the update without having to reinstall the virtual machine and/or Ubuntu?  I don't want to lose my current setup; it took ages to get right.  I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a syntax error in one of your shell's initialization files. The likeliest culprits are either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. The simplest solution is to make a backup of these two files and then overwrite them with the defaults.

1. Make a new user. You will run the necessary commands as this user who, presumably, will have a working shell. Make sure you create the user as an administrator so you can run `sudo` commands.
2. Log in as the new user and run this command (change `parallels` to the original user name, the one who has the problem):

   ```
    for i in .bashrc .profile; do 
      sudo mv ~parallels/$i ~parallels/$i.old
      sudo cp /etc/skel/$i ~parallels/
      sudo chown parallels:parallels ~parallels/$i
    done
   ```

That command will rename `.bashrc` to `.bashrc.old` and then copy the default over from `/etc/skel`. Finally, it changes the ownership of the file to `parallels` since it needs to be owned by the target user. It then does the same for `.profile`